# Add single quotes after an array element

Tags: android

I am converting centimeters into feet inches and wanted to display in standard format with quotes. I am able to get feet and inches separately in an array but stuck in appending quotes.

Output format required is `5'6"`

Here is my code:

```
 private void convertTofeetInches(EditText height_cm){
    String str = height_cm.getText().toString();
    float result = (Float.valueOf(str)/3);
    String[] arr=String.valueOf(result).split("\\.");
    int[] intArr=new int[2];
    intArr[0]=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); // feet
    intArr[1]=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); // inches
    int count = intArr.length;
}
```

Comment: What is the _standard format_?

Comment: @KNeerajLal with single quotes like 5'6"

Comment: Check my answer you will be able to display in standard format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set value on text and add quote at start because `intArr[0]` is Integer value

```
textview.setText (""+intArr[0] + " ft, " +  intArr[1] + " inches");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\'` in your string resources.

```
"message \"quote string 1\" and \"quote string 2\" end message"
```

But in views xml (eg layout.xml), you have to use HTML character entities (like ") :

```
"message &quot;quote string 1&quot; and &quot;quote string 2&quot; end message"
```

To display in Textview

```
textview.setText( intArr[0] +" \'" +   intArr[1] + " \"");
```